# Import data.sql MySQL Docker Container

Tags: mysql, docker

If I have a data.sql, how I can import database to my mysql docker container? How I can import database data. In a dockerised world this adds a layer of complexity. some methods please.

Here my docker-compose.yml:

```
nginx:
  build: ./nginx/
  container_name: nginx-container
  ports:
    - 80:80
  links:
    - php
  volumes_from:
    - app-data

php:
  build: ./php/
  container_name: php-container
  expose:
    - 9000
  links:
    - mysql
  volumes_from:
    - app-data

app-data:
  image: php:7.0-fpm
  container_name: app-data-container
  volumes:
    - ./www/html/:/var/www/html/
  command: "true"

mysql:
  image: mysql:latest
  container_name: mysql-container
  ports:
    - 3306:3306
  volumes_from:
    - mysql-data
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
    MYSQL_DATABASE: name_db
    MYSQL_USER: user
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: password

mysql-data:
  image: mysql:latest
  container_name: mysql-data-container
  volumes:
    - /var/lib/mysql
  command: "true"
```

Comment: Copy the SQL file to the container then load data infile.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I can't seem to make this work with the latest mysql or mysql:5.7. So I use mariaDB instead. Here is my `docker-compose.yaml` code.

```
version: '3'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mariadb:10.3
    container_name: mariadb
    volumes:
      - container-volume:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./dump.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dump.sql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: name_db
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

volumes:
  container-volume:
```

Comment: When I try to use this method, I end up with a directory for dump.sql? Any idea on why?

eg: bash into mariadb container & : `cd /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dump.sql/` & then I'm in a directory? 

What would cause a directory to be created instead of either not having the .sql file there at all or throwing some kind of error?

my relevant docker-compose.yml for the mariadb container:
`mariadb:
    image: mariadb:latest
...
    volumes:
     - app-vhosts:/path/before/sqldump
#creates a directory?      
     - ./path/to/sql/dump.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dump.sql
`

Comment: Remember to clear volumes first before testing, as the file will only be run on initial up. `docker-compose down --volumes && docker-compose rm -v && docker-compose up`

Answer (score 241):

You can import database afterwards:

`docker exec -i mysql-container mysql -uuser -ppassword name_db < data.sql`

Comment: If using docker-compose, you have to get the container by: `docker exec -i $(docker-compose ps -q mysql-container) mysql …`. It does not support reading from stdin at the moment, as described [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3352).

Comment: how to do this on docker-compose?

Comment: I am. getting error "the input device is not a TTY"

Comment: **FYI:** use `-p` without password for security purpose.

Comment: @kamal did you use the `-t` option for `docker exec`? Juse use `-i` to avoid the error

Comment: `docker exec -i {{CONTAINER ID}} mysql -u{{USERNAME}} -p{{PASSWORD}} {{DATABASE NAME}} < {{DUMP DATA}}.sql` , worked fo me

Comment: @iamjc015: just use docker-compose exec <container-name> <command> - no need to parse docker-compose ps output like this

Comment: I was able to import sql zip file `data.sql.zip` in localhost/phpmyadmin. I cannot import in docker container, any idea how to?

Comment: if you use docker compose you can just use `docker compose exec <serviceName>`

Comment: @AbdullaNilam You should create a new answer using `-p` without password.

Answer (score 136):

Mount your sql-dump under`/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/yourdump.sql` utilizing a volume mount

```
mysql:
  image: mysql:latest
  container_name: mysql-container
  ports:
    - 3306:3306
  volumes:
    - ./dump.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dump.sql
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
    MYSQL_DATABASE: name_db
    MYSQL_USER: user
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
```

This will trigger an import of the sql-dump during the start of the container, see 
https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/ under "Initializing a fresh instance"

Comment: +1 @EugenMayer. Definitely anyone using Compose v1 should move to latest v3 syntax: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

Comment: V3 is not a successor of V2, even if that's inconvenience. V3 is basically swarm only, it's rather a fork then a successor. See Dockers comments on this. One of the huge issues is the missing volumr_from mount possibility

Comment: Guys, remember that if you create a persistent volume for the database service, it will not check for new .sql files unless you recreate it. Lost few hours to this, I hope no one else goes through the same.

Comment: @DhwanilPatel you have to use --build --force-recreate options. 
https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/
E.g. docker-compose up --build --force-recreate

Comment: @Dazag Actually i already use this command : "sudo docker-compose up -d --force-recreate --build " but nothing happen

Answer (score 36):

Another option if you don't wanna mount a volume, but wanna dump a file from your local machine, is to pipe `cat yourdump.sql`. Like so:

```
cat dump.sql | docker exec -i mysql-container mysql -uuser -ppassword db_name
```

See:
https://gist.github.com/spalladino/6d981f7b33f6e0afe6bb

Comment: Works perfectly if `dump.sql` contains `source` files

Comment: Just what I needed to make a sql import work in my shell script. Thanks!

Answer (score 32):

Just write `docker ps` and get the container id and then write the following;

```
docker exec -i your_container_id mysql -u root -p123456 your_db_name < /Users/your_pc/your_project_folder/backup.sql
```

Answer (score 15):

Import using **docker-compose**

```
cat dump.sql | docker-compose exec -T <mysql_container> mysql -u <db-username> -p<db-password> <db-name>
```

Comment: I'm getting error - 
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insec' at line 1
read unix @->/var/run/docker.sock: read: connection reset by peer

Comment: pls check, that this warning does not already appear in your dump.sql: When you produced the file using mysqldump and gave the password on the command-line, the warning will end up in the dumped file.

Answer (score 10):

do `docker cp file.sql <CONTAINER NAME>:/file.sql` first

then `docker exec -it <CONTAINER NAME> mysql -u user -p`

then inside mysql container execute `source \file.sql`

Answer (score 9):

combine https://stackoverflow.com/a/51837876/1078784
and answers in this question, I think the best answer is:

```
cat {SQL FILE NAME} | docker exec -i {MYSQL CONTAINER NAME} {MYSQL PATH IN CONTAINER} --init-command="SET autocommit=0;"
```

for example in my system this command should look like:

```
cat temp.sql | docker exec -i mysql.master /bin/mysql --init-command="SET autocommit=0;"
```

also you can use **pv** to moniter progress:

```
cat temp.sql | pv | docker exec -i mysql.master /bin/mysql --init-command="SET autocommit=0;"
```

And the most important thing here is "--init-command" which will speed up the import progress 10 times fast.

Comment: i get stdin is not a tty...getting really bored with this, what is the solution to this?

Comment: Don't understand what your mean, maybe you can give me more detail?

Comment: using `pv temp.sql | ...`  instead of `cat temp.sql | pv | ...` allows you to see the progress of loading your sql into mysql. After the file is "sent" do mysql it will take a bit to process the content, so 100% means it's received fully but not executed fully. Still it already is an improvement for big files.

Comment: Docker-compose variant is replacing `docker exec -i` with `docker-compose exec -T`.

Answer (score 9):

I can import with this command

```
docker-compose exec -T mysql mysql -uroot -proot mydatabase < ~/Desktop/mydatabase_2019-10-05.sql
```

Comment: it hard to tell what is what, but i'm doing it the same way
`docker-compose exec -T [host] mysql -u [mysql user] -p[password] [database] < localfile.sql`. Besides that I think there is an error in your statement. There should be a space between `-u` and the username itself.

Answer (score 6):

you can follow these simple steps:

**FIRST WAY :**

first copy the SQL dump file from your local directory to the mysql container. use docker cp command

```
docker cp [SRC-Local path to sql file] [container-name or container-id]:[DEST-path to copy to]

docker cp ./data.sql mysql-container:/home
```

and then execute the mysql-container using (NOTE: in case you are using alpine version you need to replace bash with sh in the given below command.)

```
docker exec -it -u root mysql-container bash
```

and then you can simply import this SQL dump file.

```
mysql [DB_NAME] < [SQL dump file path]

mysql movie_db < /home/data.sql
```

---

**SECOND WAY : SIMPLE**

```
docker cp ./data.sql mysql-container:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

As mentioned in the mysql Docker hub official page.

Whenever a container starts for the first time, a new database is created with the specified name in MYSQL_DATABASE variable - which you can pass by setting up the environment variable *[see here how to set environment variables](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/)*

By default container will execute files with extensions .sh, .sql and .sql.gz that are found in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d folder. Files will be executed in alphabetical order. this way your SQL files will be imported by default to the database specified by the MYSQL_DATABASE variable.

for more details you can always visit the [official page](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql)

Answer (score 6):

Trying `"docker exec ... < data.sql"` in Window PowerShell responses with:

> The '<' operator is reserved for future use.

But one can wrap it out with `cmd /c` to eliminate the issue:

```
cmd /c "docker exec -i mysql-container mysql -uuser -ppassword name_db < data.sql"
```

Answer (score 2):

This one work for me

`$ docker exec -i NAME_CONTAINER_MYSQL mysql -u DB_USER -pPASSWORD DATABASE < /path/to/your/file.sql`

First if do you want to know what is the NAME_CONTAINER_MYSQL, you should use 
this command below :

`$ docker ps`

In the output column NAME you will see the NAME_CONTAINER_MYSQL that do you need to replace in the command above.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a container setting a shared directory (-v volume), and then run bash in that container. After this, you can interactively use mysql-client to execute the .sql file, from inside the container. obs: /my-host-dir/shared-dir is the .sql location in the host system.

```
docker run --detach --name=test-mysql -p host-port:container-port  --env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-root-pswd" -v /my-host-dir/shared-dir:/container-dir mysql:latest


docker exec -it test-mysql bash
```

Inside the container...

```
mysql -p < /container-dir/file.sql
```

Custom parameters:

- **test-mysql** (container name)
- **host-port** and **container-port**
- **my-root-pswd** (mysql root password)
- **/my-host-dir/shared-dir** and **/container-dir** (the host directory that will be mounted in the container, and the container location of the shared directory)

Answer (score -3):

you can copy the export file for e.g dump.sql using docker cp into the container and then import the db. if you need full instructions, let me know and I will provide