# Docker: PhpMyAdmin has an upload limit of 2048KiB

Tags: php, apache, docker, phpmyadmin, yaml

i have a docker-compose.yml that looks like this:

```
webserver:
  build: ./_docker/php
  ports:
    - 80:80
  links:
    - mysql
  volumes_from:
    - app

mysql:
  image: mysql:5.7
  environment:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: "${DB_NAME}"
    MYSQL_USER: "${DB_USER}"
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DB_ROOT_PW}"
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${DB_PW}"
  volumes:
    - ./_docker/data/db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
  volumes_from:
    - data

data:
  image: mysql:5.7
  volumes:
    - /var/lib/mysql
  command: "true"

phpmyadmin:
  image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
  ports:
    - 8080:80
  links:
    - mysql
  environment:
    PMA_HOST: mysql

app:
  image: tianon/true
  volumes:
    - .:/var/www/public_html
```

Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM php:7.0-apache
#php:7.2.2-apache
#php:5.6.33-apache

COPY php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/

COPY 000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/

RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2enmod expires
RUN a2enmod headers

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev libxml2-dev libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libmcrypt-dev libpng12.0 imagemagick
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli zip soap
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

# Install opcache
RUN docker-php-ext-install opcache
```

and the php ini like this:

```
max_input_vars = 1500
max_execution_time = 300
post_max_size=50M
upload_max_filesize=50M
```

when i start the container i have my webserver located on `http://localhost`.

i put an `index.php` with a `phpinfo();` inside it and it shows, that the `php.ini` works.

When i open `http://localhost:8080` and login to PMA it shows me that my upload limit i set to 2048KiB.

Where can i change this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You dockerfile PHP configurations won't affect phpmyadmin since it's not inside your `app` container. See https://hub.docker.com/r/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/ probably there's some tip there.

Comment: Try pulling the latest version of phpmyadmin (docker-compose pull)

Comment: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/docker/pull/241 the limit was changed to 2mb then reverted back to 512mb in this pull request.

Comment: Had the same problem and solved it by adding 

`UPLOAD_LIMIT: 1G` 

in my docker-compose.yml.

Comment: In my case for 1GB I needed to set the `UPLOAD_LIMIT` value as `1024M` to get it working.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Use like this `UPLOAD_LIMIT` env in docker. This is from my docker-compose.yml. Default value for `UPLOAD_LIMIT` is 2048K which is 2048KiB. Setting value to 300M increases it to 300MiB.

Reference: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/docker#environment-variables-summary

```
 phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: 'php7.3-phpmyadmin'
    restart: 'always'
    links:
      - mysql
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      UPLOAD_LIMIT: 300M
    ports:
      - '8082:80'
    volumes:
      - /sessions
```

Comment: For docker-compose version '3.6' the environment variable  should read UPLOAD_LIMIT=30M. Not sure about other versions

Comment: After changing environment variables you need to run `docker-compose up`. It's not enough restarting the container.

Answer (score 11):

you need to use `UPLOAD_LIMIT` inside `enviroment`, and you need to specify values with = sign, like example: `UPLOAD_LIMIT=300M`

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somerandompasswordgenerated
    ports:
      - 3306:3306

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
      - UPLOAD_LIMIT=300M
```

Comment: Yep - UPLOAD_LIMIT=300M. The "=" instead of a ":" does the trick out of the box as environment variable specifically for the section "phpmyadmin" in the .yml-file; with Docker Compose version v2.2.3 for phpMyAdmin v 5.1.3;  Docker Desktop 4.5.1 on a Windows 11 Home using WSL 2 with a docker image of MySQL 8.0.1

Comment: In my mentioned context I tested and confirmed this also applies to Docker Compose version 2.0, version 3.0 and 3.4.

Answer (score 9):

UPLOAD_LIMIT: 500M

```
mariadb:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: w-mariadb
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db_name
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: db_password
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: db_password
    volumes:
      - 'w-mariadb:/var/lib/mysql'
    networks:
      - w-network
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: w-phpmyadmin
    links:
      - mariadb
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: db_password
      PMA_HOST: mariadb
      UPLOAD_LIMIT: 500M
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8383:80'
    networks:
      - w-network
```

Answer (score 8):

I implemented `UPLOAD_LIMIT` ENV variable in

https://github.com/phpmyadmin/docker/pull/261/files#diff-80edf79b0f382a3c6e871ac209ffd6abR57

Answer (score 5):

I edit this file :

```
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/phpmyadmin-misc.ini
```

and set new values :

```
post_max_size=64M
upload_max_filesize=64M
```

It works fine.

Answer (score 4):

the following worked very well.
My docker-compose.yml contains this:

```
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: some-name
    env_file:
      - phpmyadmin.env
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    volumes:
```

The following entry was added to the phpmyadmin.env: UPLOAD_LIMIT=256MB
The larger number (Maximal: 256MiB) showed up right after the container was brought down and was back up again.

Comment: It should be `256M` and not `256MB`

Comment: Man, I was trying this to fix this for like 8 - 10 hours when setting up laradock on my new PC (old one works perfectly). Somehow, this was the only thing that worked. To clarify, I just created a phpmyadmin.env file in root of docker compose folder, with that single line of UPLOAD_LIMIT=? and a newline at the end, and referenced it in phpmyadmin service like you did. THANK YOU SO MUCH! God bless you, sir.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I couldn't fix it with UPLOAD_LIMIT, so without further debugging I needed a quick solution even if it's temporary:

1. open phpmyadmin container terminal: `docker exec -it container_name bash`
2. If you don't have vim or nano editor install one: `apt-get update`, `apt-get install vim`
3. create config file: `vi /usr/local/php/conf.d/myconf.ini`
4. with this content: `post_max_size=50M` `upload_max_filesize=50M`
5. restart container

**Remember** these changes will be gone when container is recreated, it's just a temporary solution. Try working with UPLOAD_LIMIT as suggested in previous answer.

**UPDATE**
Tried again with setting upload_limit environment, but still without luck, so found another solution:
created a file say `uploads.ini` with this content:

```
post_max_size=50M 
upload_max_filesize=50M
```

and link it to container volume :

```
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    links: 
      - mysql:db
    ports:
      - 8084:80
    volumes:
      - ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php-phpmyadmin.ini
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: something
      #UPLOAD_LIMIT: 3000000000 <-- didn't work
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to install from phpmyadmin docker image and with docker run, you can exec this.

docker run --name your-image-name -d --link mysql-docker:db --env "UPLOAD_LIMIT=256M" phpmyadmin

This works for me and enable upload to 256MB SQL file.

Answer (score 0):

Need rebuild container after change `UPLOAD_LIMIT`

```
docker-compose up -d --force-recreate --build phpmyadmin
```

Answer (score 0):

For Docker Desktop users: when you run the image, open the Optional settings and at the Environment variables you can set the Variable to UPLOAD_LIMIT and the Value to 256M.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

When I am trying to solve using UPLOAD_LIMIT= 500M getting a error. UPLOAD_LIMIT only work Kilobyte formate for me not Megabyte.

```
phpmyadmin:
image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
links:
  - mysql
environment:
  MYSQL_USERNAME: ${MYSQL_ROOT_USER}
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
  PMA_HOST: mysql
  PMA_PORT: ${MYSQL_PORT:-3306}
  UPLOAD_LIMIT: 102400k
depends_on:
  - mysql
restart: always
networks:
  - nestjs-network
ports:
  - ${PHPMYADMIN_PORT:-8085}:80
```