# Access denied for user 'user=bn_moodle'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb, moodle

I'm getting this error from a MariaDB database inside a docker image, the docker image I'm using [this Moodle image](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/moodle/) and starting up the instances using docker-compose up.

I just want to restore a dump in the docker database, I'm following t[his thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43880026/import-data-sql-mysql-docker-container/43880563) and I'm testing this command:

`docker exec -i mysql-container mysql -uuser -ppassword name_db < data.sql`

the docker-compose.yml is the following:

```
version: '2'
services:
  mariadb:
    image: 'bitnami/mariadb:latest'
    environment:
      - MARIADB_USER=bn_moodle
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=bitnami_moodle
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    volumes:
      - 'mariadb_data:/bitnami'
  moodle:
    image: 'bitnami/moodle:3'
    environment:
      - MARIADB_HOST=mariadb
      - MARIADB_PORT_NUMBER=3306
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_USER=bn_moodle
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_NAME=bitnami_moodle
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    volumes:
      - 'moodle_data:/bitnami'
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
volumes:
  mariadb_data:
    driver: local
  moodle_data:
    driver: local
```

So I'm doing this:

```
docker exec -i docker-instance-id mysql -uuser=bn_moodle bitnami_moodle < Dump20190402.sql
```

since I don't see any user password in the yaml file, I'm not passing it, assuming I can log in to the database with no password.

but I'm getting this error:

> Access denied for user 'user=bn_moodle'@'localhost' (using password:
>   NO)

Any advice will be appreciated it!
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your exec command. It should be `--user=bn_moodle` or `-u bn_moodle` not `--uuser`

```
docker exec -i docker-instance-id mysql --user=bn_moodle bitnami_moodle < Dump20190402.sql
```

Comment: thanks seems like I can login, now I got the specified key was too long; mas key is 767 bytes

Comment: That error is specific of the dump you're trying to import. Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814532/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes