# mysql> source backupfile.sql is not worked for me

Tags: php, mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have tried all the solutions which given followed link:
[Solution link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-do-i-import-an-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql) But I failed.

I have exec mysql instance with docker

Code
Absolute path `mysql> source  D:\dc@vsw\XXXX\suranabr_dev01_1.sql`

Error `Failed to open file 'D:\dc@vsw\XXXX\suranabr_dev01_1.sql', error: 2`

Comment: Also this command  is not worked for me.

`$ docker exec -i some-mysql sh -c 'exec mysql -uroot -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"' < /some/path/on/your/host/all-databases.sql
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you not placing the `backupfile.sql` in dockerfile so it will be restored automatically once the container is up?

```
FROM mysql
COPY backupfile.sql  /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

> When a container is started for the first time, a new database with the specified name will be created and initialized with the provided configuration variables. Furthermore, it will execute files with extensions .sh, .sql and .sql.gz that are found in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`

[mysql-docker-Initializing a fresh instance](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql)

OR

```
docker exec -i mysql-container mysql -uuser -ppassword name_db < backup.sql
```

[Import data.sql MySQL Docker Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43880026/import-data-sql-mysql-docker-container)

Or with docker-compose

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - $PWD/backup.sql : /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/backup.sql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test
```

Comment: I can not  put into docker-compose files because database restoration is only one time process...


And  for  

`docker exec -i mysql-container mysql -uuser -ppassword name_db < backup.sql` 

 Its show me error  

**At line:1 char:81
+ ... l-server-80 sh -c 'exec mysql -uroot -proot suranabr_dev01' < D:\dc@v ...
+                                                                 ~
The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RedirectionNotSupported**

Comment: the dockerfile also only write once if mount directory to `/var/lib/mysql` or database path. if database already exist it will not overide the existing one

Comment: Can we go with chat room?

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218003/room-for-adiii-and-vickysw

Comment: Not worked for me when I  bind the volumes in mysql service in docker-compose.yml files