# wordpress docker with automatic wordpress configuration

Tags: wordpress, docker

I am following the documentation to set up a docker compose of wordpress here:
https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/

Everything works fine and I can open the site to find the usual wordpress installation script. I would be able to complete the installation, but I was wondering if there is an automatic way to set everything up.

The database details are stored in the docker compose file so this might not be so difficult. Additionally, the site title, default user and so on needs to be defined somewhere but due to my insufficient knowledge about docker I don't know where to start.

Has anyone any ideas where to start?

Comment: You could definitely have a pre-provisioned database and import it in the MySQL container. Worth reading: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43880026/2123530

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε what a simple and elegant solution. Thank you very much!